# Swift 3 Unable to make phone call with the String transferred from the tableviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, button, phone-call

Thanks for the help in advance. I don't know why when I try to make a phone call with a button function as below

```
@IBAction func phonebutton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let number1 = URL(string: "telprompt://\(phonenumber)") else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(number1 as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}
```

it doesn't show anything.

To explain more, the String value "phonenumber" is transferred from another tableview cell prepare for segue function as below

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any? ) {
    if (segue.identifier == "indooradventureseg"){
        let transfertopage = segue.destination as! indooradventuretablecellViewController
        transfertopage.phonenumber = info[sender as! Int][4] as! String

    }
```

Here's the code in the ViewController where I put my call button in

class indooradventuretablecellViewController: UIViewController {

```
var phonenumber = "31617543"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    phonenumberlabel.text = phonenumber
    phonebuttonlabel.setTitle(phonenumber, for: .normal)
}
```

However, if I put any other String initiated within the ViewController or simply put the phone number on the button function like below, the phone call function does work.

```
@IBAction func phonebutton(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let number1 = URL(string: "telprompt://12345678") else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(number1 as! URL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)

}
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: In @IBAction func phonebutton(...) add a print(phonenumber). What does it print?

Comment: What is the exact actual value of `phonenumber`? It can't have spaces or any other invalid phone number characters.

Comment: FYI - `tel` and `telprompt` URLs don't need the `//`.

Comment: phonenumber is transferred from an array 

var info = [
["Peter","UT","Austin Street","Gaming","3580 0030",CLLocation(latitude: 22.319507, longitude: 114.170161),UIImage(named: "helloworld"),UIImage(named: "helloworld"),"field for km","http://google.com"],...]

Comment: Again, what is the exact actual value of `phonenumber`?

Comment: I know why now..because my string has space it was "3580 0030"...thanks Maddy!!

Comment: @Howard: how did u resolve the space issue then? delete space and then make a call to the new value?

Comment: @Lohit, just make it like "35800030", no space in between